# iOS read data from a bit more 'complex' .plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, plist

I know this question had been asked for several times, but I have trouble reading data in Xcode iOS. The problem was to achieve an implementation without having the keys for NSDictionaries hardcoded in the code.

Let's say, we have this .plist:

[This is my plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq08B.png)

In this case I want to access the name and address from the restaurants dynamically without accessing the data by a hardcoded string.

Background of this is that I try to access the data on every cell on a grouped UITableView for iOS.

Anyone has some good information about this? 
Generally (normally I code in c#) I know how to access dictionaries. But in this case, there are nested dictionaries with arrays which get me really confused and also frustrating :(

Comment: Why dont use JSON or XML instead....?

Comment: uuuhm, yeah. Interesting question... I never thought of this. I could use it too. Thats right. Actually I try to understand how to access nested Dictionaries in Xcode. That might be possible...

Comment: With JSON its very easy and have a lot of framework to help u parse it to objects even with nested data (and u don't have to understand much at all), if u want to understand dictionary there're a lot of tutorial over internet also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyListName" ofType:@"plist"];
//Plist should exist in main bundle
NSDictionary *root = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

Then in your case your first value is a array in dictionary read that object in an array like,
NSArray * restaurantsArray = [names objectForKey:@"restaurants"];
Then so forth  You know what type of object exist in the hierarchy just call respective methods of each,
like objectForKey for dictionary.
objectAtIndex for array.